# Js script too slow on IE 7 IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, offset

I created a javascript script. The idea is when user hover on product, one new element will appear. Here is my script:

```
$('.product-item').hover(function(){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    $('.product-hover')
        .html("<div class='product-item'>" + $(this).html() + "</div>")
        .css({
           display: 'block',
           left: offset.left,
           top: offset.top,
           width: $(this).width()
        });
});
```

It is working fine on Firefox and Chrome. But on IE7 and 8, the browser stop working for a while (about 10 seconds), when I try to hover. You can not click on `.product-hover` or on his children elements (e.g. links and buttons).

Could you tell me why and how to solve it.
Thank you so much

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I am using jQuery 1.7.1.Thanks

Comment: Does this happen the first time you hover over a product, or after hovering over several others?

Comment: Hmm, I often see perfomance problems when I check my sites, often the problems are gone after reloading the page or restarting the browser or clearing the cache... We all love IE.

Comment: Does this happen the first time you hover over a product, or after hovering over several others?--->It happen the first time I hover.Thanks

Comment: What's in `$(this).html()`?

Comment: What's in $(this).html()?--->It contents pure html of children elements(e.g name,image,add to cart,...).I think it is not cause of that error.Thanks

Comment: I tried to update jquery to 1.9.1 ,but problem is still there

Comment: Do you have warnings or errors in the console or showing up?

Comment: Do you have warnings or errors in the console or showing up?-->There is no errors in the console.

Comment: there is no alerts either?

Comment: there is no alerts either?---->No.No errors,no alerts.I don't know why.Thanks

Comment: Stop Using IE7 and IE8 Then. It's old. Force upgrade to IE9 and IE10

Answer (score 0):

This is what I know about IE8 and IE7 causing a similar behavior as you just described:

IE8 and earlier versions by default set a threshold limit for time-out is set to 5,000,000 statements.

Microsoft released a patch to correct this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175500

Please note that microsoft also indicates that which is the registry entry to increase this to any level if necessary:

Using a Registry Editor such as Regedt32.exe, open this key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Styles
```

Note If the Styles key is not present, create a new key that is called Styles.

Create a new DWORD value called "MaxScriptStatements" under this key, and set the value to the desired number of script statements.

If you are not sure about which value you need to set this to, you can set it to a DWORD value of 0xFFFFFFFF to avoid the dialog box.